# How to create an auto increment id column using Spark (pure SQL no Python)

Tags: sql, apache-spark

How can I generate an ID number in Spark SQL? In the python interface, Spark has the monotonically_increasing_id() function. But I do not know how to realize this function in SQL grammar. I want to create a table from an old table with some string operations and establish an id column for the new table.

Comment: There is also a `monotonically_increasing_id()` function in SQL syntax. Please refer to: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#monotonically_increasing_id

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick I hope:

`ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY myColumn)`

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is best to use Spark-SQL syntax for the auto-increment:

The syntax is as following:
GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY
[ ( [ START WITH start ] [ INCREMENT BY step ] ) ]

The start with and increment values have defaults so you only need this:

**Example:**

create table gen1 (
id long GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, t string
)

This works on Delta tables in Databricks for instance. There it needs runtime version 10.4 or above.

Sources:
[1] https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/is-delta-table-with-auto-increment-column-as-unique-identifier/td-p/17768 
[2] [Auto increment id in delta table while inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156253/auto-increment-id-in-delta-table-while-inserting)